# InnoSetup script uses JSONConfig.dll to read a json file but fails to retrieve key/values from file

Tags: json, inno-setup, pascalscript

I have an InnoSetup script that reads a json file to retrieve some values (bool and strings mostly).
To achieve this I'm using Tlamas JSONConfig.dll downloaded from here: https://github.com/nsdevaraj/inno-json-config.
the problem now is that it fails to read the values from json-file and therefore only uses the default ones given as parameter to the functions. I've tried to debug it but not sure how to, added logs to this and tried to update the JSONConfig.dll by adding debug logging to its code but get only exceptions then.

What am I doing wrong here? Appreciate all the help I can get.

My original code is company code so I'm using the examples given in inno-json-config to do the same thing and failing, so will post that code instead.
I'm using Inno Setup 5.6.1. Variable WideString is not recognized and I changed it to String.

Example.iss

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program
OutputDir=userdocs:Inno Setup Examples Output

[Files]
Source: "C:\inno-json-config-master\JSONConfig.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[code]
function JSONQueryString(FileName, Section, Key, Default: String;
  var Value: String; var ValueLength: Integer): Boolean;
  external 'JSONQueryString@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';
function JSONQueryBoolean(FileName, Section, Key: String; 
  Default: Boolean; var Value: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'JSONQueryBoolean@files:jsonconfig.dll stdcall';

function BoolToStr(Value: Boolean): string;
begin
  Result := 'True';
  if not Value then
    Result := 'False';
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  FileName: String;
  IntValue: Integer;
  StrValue: String;
  StrLength: Integer;
  BoolValue: Boolean;
begin
  FileName := 'C:\inno-json-config-master\Example.json';
  if FileExists(FileName) then begin
   Log('file found');
   end else begin
   Log('file not found');
  end;
  
  SetLength(StrValue, 16);
  StrLength := Length(StrValue);

  Log('StrValue_before:' + StrValue);
  Log('BoolValue_before: ' + BoolToStr(BoolValue));

  if JSONQueryString(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_1', 'Default', StrValue, StrLength) then 
  begin
    MsgBox('Section_1:Key_1=' + StrValue, mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
  Log('Section_1:Key_1=' + StrValue);
  
  if JSONQueryBoolean(FileName, 'Section_1', 'Key_3', True, BoolValue) then 
  begin
    MsgBox('Section_1:Key_3=' + BoolToStr(BoolValue), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;                
  Log('Section_1:Key_3=' + BoolToStr(BoolValue));

  if JSONQueryBoolean(FileName, 'Section_2', 'Key_3', True, BoolValue) then 
  begin
    MsgBox('Section_2:Key_3=' + BoolToStr(BoolValue), mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
  Log('Section_2:Key_3=' + BoolToStr(BoolValue));
end;
```

```
{
    "Section_1": {
        "Key_1": "String 1",
        "Key_2": "1",
        "Key_3": "True"
    },
    "Section_2": {
        "Key_1": "String 2",
        "Key_2": "2",
        "Key_3": "False"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to solve my problem and it is to use an ini file instead. Inno setup has built-in functions to read/write from/to an ini file. This way I save lots of time and ini is easy to read for a user as well.